# Android: custom font not work for inflate layout

Tags: android, layout-inflater, custom-font

I added my fonts to `res/font/k.ttf`

And create `myfont.xml` font like below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/k"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/k"
        />
</font-family>
```

Finally, I use it for `textview` and `edittext`

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
                android:text="test" />
```

This code work fine, but if I use inflate, my custom font not work

My code :

```
myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
```

Comment: Do you encounter any exception? If you do post it as well.

Comment: How are you creating or obtaining that `inflater`?

Comment: @Pawel I cant understand your comment. Can you please explain more?

Comment: @MikeM. I create `inflater` in `applcation` class and use it on my activity : `inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Comment: That's likely your problem, then. The `Application` will not have the appropriate resources, and is probably just ignoring those `app` attributes. Get the `LayoutInflater` from the current `Activity`, either with `Activity#getLayoutInflater()`, or `LayoutInflater.from(Activity)`.